# advice for setting ups tor. newbie

Tags: configuration

I just bought a new MacBook Pro. I would like to use tor. but I use safari and mail for my business ,can i set up tor so I can use that separately from safari and still maintain anonymity.. or do I have to reconfigure settings and use only tor?  this is my first new laptop in 10 years so I am behind the times in setting up privacy browsers and trying to stay invisible on the internet. any help or advice would be appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest you start with Tor Browser and look at anything more sophisticated after you have done this.

Answer (score 1):

Tor is the name for a software communication protocol that works to provide anonymity for the user. The Tor network can be utilized by lots of software for example I can route my ssh session over tor.

Tor is mostly accessed using the Tor browser a browser based upon firefox that is used to access .onion domains as well as the normal web through the tor network. If you just want to use a browser for anonymity and accessing .onion domains you want the the Tor Browser. If you want to route any and all traffic from your machine you'll be looking at using the tor software to route all traffic though it, tho you may inadvertently leave yourself open to leaks and a solution such as Tails/Whonix might be better for that.

So your options are use the tor browser to browse the normal web anonymously and/or access .onion domains, keeping your safari/mail connecting normally.

Install Tor the software to try route any and all network activity through the tor network, tho potentially would lead to problems/leaks/wrong configs exposing yourself. If this is your goal, something like tails/whonix might be more suited. 
Or a separate device that you connect too that will try route any packets you may have missed, such as the onionpi.

Answer (score 0):

in case of Mac you better use an external routing box - there're lots of "surprises" on modern Mac OS X versions with Tor. It will also route all your srvices *safely* through Tor, no leaks or leftovers will be possible.